# VBA: copy/paste loop only takes the last sheet into account/overwriting previous sheets

Tags: vba, excel

**Expected situation:** I have a loop which is checking all sheets of a workbook for certain keywords, copy/pasting them according to certain conditions and ist creating a new workbook for every sheet with the said values.

***Example:***

> Source Workbook with Sheet1,Sheet2 and Sheet3 **--->**
>   New_Workbook_1(with values of Sheet1), New_Workbook_2(with values of
>   Sheet2), New_Workbook_3(with values of Sheet3)

**Actual situation:** only the values of the last sheet of the workbook are pasted into the newly created workbooks...I can't tell why? .

***Example:***

> Source Workbook with Sheet1,Sheet2 and Sheet3 **--->** New_Workbook_1(with
>   values of Sheet3), New_Workbook_2(with values of Sheet3),
>   New_Workbook_3(with values of Sheet3)

```
Public Sub TransferFile(TemplateFile As String, SourceFile As String)
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(SourceFile) 'open source

    Dim rFnd As Range
    Dim r1st As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr(1 To 4) As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Dim wbTemplate As Workbook
    Dim NewWbName As String

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    For Each wsSource In wbSource.Worksheets 'loop through all worksheets in source workbook
        Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(TemplateFile) 'open new template

        '/* Definition of the value range */

arr(1) = "XX"
arr(2) = "Data 2"
arr(3) = "Test 3"
arr(4) = "XP35"

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    For Each ws In wbSource.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name
        Set rFnd = ws.UsedRange.Find(what:=arr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rFnd Is Nothing Then
            Set r1st = rFnd
            Do
                If i = 1 Then
                    wbTemplate.Sheets("Header").Range("A3").Value = "XX"  

                ElseIf i = 2 Then
                    wbTemplate.Sheets("Header").Range("B9").Value = rFnd.Offset(0, 1).Value 


                ElseIf i = 3 Then
                   wbTemplate.Sheets("Header").Range("D7").Value = rFnd.Offset(0, 2).Value  



                ElseIf i = 4 Then
                    wbTemplate.Sheets("MM1").Range("A8").Value = "2" 


                End If
                Set rFnd = ws.UsedRange.FindNext(rFnd)
            Loop Until r1st.Address = rFnd.Address
        End If
    Next
Next


NewWbName = Left(wbSource.Name, InStr(wbSource.Name, ".") - 1)

For i = 1 To 9
    'check for existence of proposed filename
    If Len(Dir(wbSource.Path & Application.PathSeparator & NewWbName & "_V" & i & ".xlsx")) = 0 Then
        wbTemplate.SaveAs wbSource.Path & Application.PathSeparator & NewWbName & "_V" & i & ".xlsx"
        Exit For
    End If
Next i


    wbTemplate.Close False 'close template
    Next wsSource

    wbSource.Close False 'close source

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoit on  line ( by pressing F9 in that line) and run the program. When vba stopped at that line, before pressing F5 to continue, go to your folder and open newly created workbook and see is it true or not. continue and share the results to find out where is the issue.